# Event not firing on a newly created window with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I am trying to fire an event when my newly created window is going to close and I am getting absolutely nothing.

Here is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
var loginWindow = "";

class LoginPopup extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    handleUnload = (ev) =>{
        debugger;
        ev.preventDefault();
        console.log("Hey it worked!");
        return "";
    };

    componentDidMount(){
        loginWindow = window.open('http://localhost:8030/google/login', '_blank', 'menubar=0,modal=yes');
        debugger;
        console.log(loginWindow);
        loginWindow.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.handleUnload);
    }

    render(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser console? Does `loginWindow` equal `null` after calling `window.open()`?

Comment: No I am not getting error in the browser console. Everything works except the events I am trying to set on `loginWindow`.

Comment: I did not try your code, but there is one thing, that I think could cause your problem:
`loginWindow = window.open('http://localhost:8030/google/login', '_blank', 'menubar=0,modal=yes')`
you are using the attribute '_blank', which will open the link in a new tab. So i don't think the beforeunload event will fire in you current browser tab.
But I'm not sure about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `componentWillUnmount()` lifecicle method to fire your event.

See docs here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount

Answer (score 0):

There is one package `react-new-window` which provides the exact functionality of new window event handling. You can install that package and handle desire events.

I have developed the sample example in codesanbox :

[image: Edit serene-sky-5cznf]

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import NewWindow from "react-new-window";
const windowFeatures = "toolbar=0,status=0,fullscreen=yes";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      openNewWindow: false
    };
  }

  openNewWindow = () => {
    this.setState({
      openNewWindow: true
    });
  };

  onUnload = () => {
    alert("Close Window Event Fired..!");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.openNewWindow && (
          <NewWindow onUnload={this.onUnload} features={windowFeatures}>
            <h1>Hi </h1>
          </NewWindow>
        )}
        <button onClick={this.openNewWindow}> Open New Window </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```